# disable debug info in mongodb log file

Tags: mongodb

Why is the debug info being added to log file even if there is no such option present in config file?

tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

```
2015-08-20T19:46:58.496+0530 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52564 #29378865 (229 connections now open)
2015-08-20T19:46:58.501+0530 [conn29378865] end connection 127.0.0.1:52564 (228 connections now open)
2015-08-20T19:46:58.502+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "c79d3312-8c39-4721-996e-310f6c810e69" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:4 locks(micros) r:210752 nreturned:0 reslen:20 143ms
2015-08-20T19:46:58.735+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "10a01624-8a47-4ec4-a260-f11a83e7e195" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:3 locks(micros) r:206983 nreturned:0 reslen:20 107ms
2015-08-20T19:46:58.878+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "edc0792f-8009-4b37-acdc-765308d87006" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:2 locks(micros) r:225245 nreturned:0 reslen:20 140ms
2015-08-20T19:46:59.597+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "5cc70052-081b-49f0-8f39-fa32337508cc" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:3 locks(micros) r:261268 nreturned:0 reslen:20 152ms
2015-08-20T19:46:59.792+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "c72608ff-0474-4ac3-a538-8426a229786d" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:153281 nreturned:0 reslen:20 101ms
2015-08-20T19:46:59.924+0530 [conn29376536] query email3.email query: { messageguid: "<dc704c13-bcc4-4c37-a885-6c3a83fbfc80" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:85116 nscannedObjects:85116 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:166382 nreturned:0 reslen:20 124ms
```

I have checked that Profiling level is 0

```
> db.getProfilingLevel()
0
```

The log file size is around 26 GB.
Is there anything I will miss if I truncate this file?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to check your component logging levels and not the database profiling level.

**Viewing the log levels:**

Within the mongodb shell, run the `db.getLogComponents()` command to get a comprehensive list of the logging levels assigned to the various components. You will get an output that looks similar to the following:

```
{
    "verbosity" : 0,
    "accessControl" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "command" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "control" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "geo" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "index" : {
    "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "network" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "query" : {
        "verbosity" : 2
    },
    "replication" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "sharding" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "storage" : {
        "verbosity" : -1,
        "journal" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "write" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    }
}
```

If you are noticing increased *query* verbosity in your log then look at the `query.verbosity` value from the aforementioned `db.getLogComponents` output. If the value is greater than **0** then that will explain the extra verbosity. Note, if the value is **-1** then the logging level for that component defaults to the level specified in `verbosity` (the system logging level default).

In the example above, the `query.verbosity` level is **2** whereas all the others have a value of **-1** which means that they will default to the `verbosity` level of **0**.

**Changing the value in the shell:**

If you want to change the logging level for a component then use the `db.setLogLevel()` command by passing in the level and the component. For example, the following will set the query verbosity to the default.

```
> db.setLogLevel(-1, "query")
```

The level may range from the least verbose of **0** to the most verbose of **5**. Setting a level to **-1** will default the component's verbosity to the established default value.

**References:**

- [db.getLogComponents](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.getLogComponents/#db.getLogComponents)
- [db.setLogLevel](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/#db.setLogLevel)
- [Log Messages](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/log-messages/) for information on the logging messages.